# DKIM Google App Engine - Outlook spam

Tags: google-app-engine, email, outlook, dkim

I have a GoogleAppEngine account with Java support. I'm using the built-in sending email system.

Whenever I send an email to an Outlook account, my mail gets in the spam folder. Everything seems ok in other email services (such as Gmail).

Here's the header that Outlook shows about the email:

```
x-store-info:CnuewmGKkJzNjuOw4Ko28wB3rXpWYbsxzn6LamLIePyzzIVpobtew5KPPrAIzOoZUnC9vu9zSb8HGyKERL/zU0axrl5kqWyDAT9m9UymcrmoErdxSDPHAo0hcd6lZ4afPNbbb2rs0dM=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 209.85.192.198) smtp.mailfrom=3zNaSVAwbAG8haTebbiR-PbZNccVQ.TbbTYRhfRePbagRag.PbZ@M3KW2WVRGUFZ5GODRSRYTGD7.apphosting.bounces.google.com; dkim=none header.d=mabools.com; x-hmca=none header.id=from@mabools.com
X-SID-PRA: from@mabools.com
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-SID-Result: NONE
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTE7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0xO1NDTD00
X-Message-Info: o9rlR4nWDTecj0Bvtea2jZE1PdKhfKNxddiddnlyR2dws7xPQ2YDsrK+mnMMw7I1O0YZgNF0dQX5iNEFswNLhDL9VjG1eTp9YdTRkYiNUonG10SddolxTimtTGsPthA3rDvmt7NZD8uYRUauBYGadUP5Vd3yw9X+iLK4dFF8dBTRiB/I3lemXORduWH3L5HlLpALuE+RyaxoV6F8g0YIi4R0jh8K0MKqNEsJWG0Tuik=
Received: from mail-pd0-f198.google.com ([209.85.192.198]) by BAY004-MC4F42.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.22751);
 Thu, 18 Dec 2014 05:29:48 -0800
Received: by mail-pd0-f198.google.com with SMTP id fp1so6822518pdb.1
    for <destination@outlook.com>; Thu, 18 Dec 2014 05:29:48 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
    h=mime-version:reply-to:message-id:date:subject:from:to:content-type;
    bh=MaNe87hfEgemAvKhv88sKlnGBnjV5G6JAq77+fBKjqs=;
    b=GhLpgQIVcaQ1zcs63phsZKJd42a7OMExCoTbXc9HkZMgMgIF8+RnJbMIn7VRzTE6ub
     /9Wn0Kq23hkwjbxK+TzDfh8+NoqFddcRDERvLiu5T9B3oArm6Ibf60odZ1wz/WVdXoFI
     Dp1UVJ/Sbf5ZkH2tqR7J8ZpEp7nrPqzPRwTQhgMqvKeVoIdplNAfvXOaJtW4DGH+3ELT
     gA6UFnZdZzHzbGN09SIbLRdkuQZSwrzGmqZ9sZt/WP5Y6XD0/Tp+GsyHIXb+d+tmf9XY
     ohBHevlR6Nc5rsD6cEqlhbDPsrZeA5EaWnUZWBrB2tZPnmjbnvI4IOxX7C7Vo9r3l/i6
     cVUA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.66.243.36 with SMTP id wv4mr1591290pac.37.1418909388189;Thu, 18 Dec 2014 05:29:48 -0800 (PST)
Reply-To: Ungroove - out of the routine <reply@ungroove.com>
X-Google-Appengine-App-Id: s~ungroove-com
X-Google-Appengine-App-Id-Alias: ungroove-com
Message-ID: <047d7b111b2b0d3e4c050a7d9670@google.com>
```

I guess it's a DKIM problem (or not?). So I did some searches and I found this link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/173535?hl=en

But I'm stuck with step1 that says "login in Google Admin Console". 
I go there, the page asks me which Google Account I want to use, I select it, I type my credentials, the page refreshes and asks me again the account I want to use!! No way to get forward.